# Demystifying Angular scope inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using the `inspector-gadget` [AngularUI module](http://softwaredoug.github.io/inspector-gadget/#/home) as a footer cell of a [Angular UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/)

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" col-index="renderIndex">
   <inspector-gadget data-container="body" data-placement="bottom" ng-controller="FooterCtrl">
   <a id="{{ 'popover-' + col.field }}" name="{{ col.displayName }}">{{ col.getAggregationValue() }}</a>

    <inspector-title style="width: 100%">
       <span class="text-info"><strong>{{ col.field }}</strong></span>
    </inspector-title>

    <inspector-content>
       <div>
          <select class="form-control" popover ng-model="col.colDef.stat" ng-options="stat as stat for stat in col.getRenderContainer().grid.stats"></select>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" maxlength="5">
       </div>
     </inspector-content>
   </inspector-gadget>
</div>
```

UI grid passes the `col` variable to the outermost scope here but it fails to show up in the inner scopes. I was expecting it'd be visible to the inner scopes for `inspector-content` and `inspector title` as well.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CoFBNvIsMF40MfCemqBP?p=preview) with the issue here.
See how `{{ col.field }}` isn't rendered.

Comment: Isn't this related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912227/how-to-pass-data-to-angular-strap-popover ?

Comment: Not sure if it's related but the approach used in that question i.e create popover on the fly, might be useful for me too. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Thanks! That approach worked. I'll post an answer soon.